# Android Studio 3.5 Overhead

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I installed the latest Android Studio 3.5 and Hello World app size is 1.4 MB which was half MB with Android Studio 3.4, what is the problem?

Comment: what about your old projects? did u see an increase in size

Comment: I don't have any old projects

Comment: I don't think you need to worry about anything make your app and analyze the apk for issues, if any.

Comment: The largest part of the hello-world app is most likely the android support library. This library grows the higher the API level is as more compatibility code is included into the app. Therefore Android Studio itself is not responsible, it is the now higher tragetAPI version.